# Do the "non-finite 'haber' + participle" constructions have a name of their own?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, participio, infinitivo, gerundio, verbos-auxiliares

Spanish non-finite or impersonal forms are: **infinitive** or ***infinitivo*** (CANTAR), **gerund** or ***gerundio*** (CANTANDO) and **past participle** or ***participio*** (CANTADO).
Then we have a number of tenses where the verb itself is conjugated: CANTO, CANTABA, CANTARÉ, etc. These are called **simple tenses** or ***tiempos simples***.
Then we have tenses where an auxiliar verb *haber* is conjugated instead, followed by the participle of the original verb: HE CANTADO, HABÍA CANTADO, HABRÉ CANTADO, etc. These are called **compound tenses** or ***tiempos compuestos***.

Then we have other forms where the auxiliar verb *haber* itself uses an impersonal form, and is followed by the original verb's participle: HABER CANTADO, HABIENDO CANTADO.

**Questions:**

- Do these constructions have a name?
  Searching for [`haber infinitive`](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=haber%20infinitive) I found [Using the verb Haber in its infinitive form](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27899) which explains how forms like HABER CANTADO are used, but it doesn't mention a specific name for them.
- Does something like HABIDO CANTADO even exist? how would it be (or was) used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the conjugation of the verb [`temer`](https://www.rae.es/publicaciones/temer), or in this article about [`modelos de conjugación verbal`](https://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/modelos-de-conjugacion-verbal) you can find that the mentioned forms are called "formas no personales compuestas".

So basically you have `infinitivo simple` which is usually called just `infinitivo`:

> temer

`infinitivo compuesto`:

> haber temido

`gerundio simple`:

> temiendo

`gerundio compuesto`:

> habiendo temido

and finally the `participio`

> temido

which doesn't have a compound equivalent.

I also found this [article](http://www.livingspanish.com/Infinitivo-gerundio-participio-I.htm) in spanish and english.